# adding a class object to a array

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

i am writing a a program that has two classes. the first class has an array  which will be able to add the other class into its array with a length of 10. however i get the error saying "Cannot find Symbol".
so my question is how do i add a seperate class to the array of an another class?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HomeInventoryManager

private int[] listOfInventoryItems;
/**
 * Initialise the home inventory manager.
 */

public HomeInventoryManager()
{
    listOfInventoryItems = new int[10];
    InventoryItem = 0;  **i get the error here saying it cannot find the symbol variable InventoryItem** 
}

public void addInventoryItem()
{
    listOfInventoryItems[InventoryItem] = anInt;
    inventoryItem++;
}
```

[image: UML diagram]

Comment: Whether the **inventoryItem** an int or a separate class?

Comment: it is a separate class

Comment: Can you put the code of inventory Item. Otherwise can't tell the exact solution. In short, you should call a method in that class to increment the inventoyItem count.

Answer (score 1):

That's obvious. You haven't declared what is **inventoryItem**. It whould be declared at the top of the class similar to the declaration of **listofInventoryItems**

```
public class HomeInventoryManager{

    private int[] listOfInventoryItems;
    private int inventoryItem;
    /**
     * Initialise the home inventory manager.
     */
    public HomeInventoryManager()
    {
        listOfInventoryItems = new int[10];
        inventoryItem = 0;
    }
    //your code here
}
```

Also,  in the other 2 methods, you have 2 spellings for inventoryItem. Correct it also.

Comment: the inventoryitem item is a separate class though

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HomeInventoryManager{


private int[] listOfInventoryItems;
private int InventoryItem;

//constructor
public HomeInventoryManager()
{
    listOfInventoryItems = new int[10];
    InventoryItem = 0;
}

public void addInventoryItem()
{
    listOfInventoryItems[0] = anInt; 
    inventoryItem++;
}
}
```